TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
I want to use an ancestor class TMyFrame =class(TFrame) for all my frames. The compiler accepts everything I write, but when I start the program I get various error messages one after the other, such as: E.g. the TextHeight property was not found in the base class. How do I move forward with this? Thanks.
Here is my example:
unit MyFrame;

interface

type
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  strict private
    MyList: TList;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property ClientHeight;
    property ClientWidth;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  MyList := TList.Create;
end;

destructor TWinWebFrame.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(MyList);
  inherited;
end;

end.

I then derive my frames from this class.

TWinWebFrame ist TMyFrame, sorry
